# What's a shorter way of saying, "Can you increase the temperature of the air conditioning please?"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm a little sensitive to cold temperatures and will often ask my roommate to increase the temperature of the air conditioning as he usually has the remote control.

One time, I said, "**Dude, can you turn up the air con?**" He thought I was asking him to increase the fan velocity of the air conditioning.

I thought of multiple ways of shortening this sentence myself. Here are a couple of my attempts:

"**Can you make the air con hotter?**" But this would mean that I would like to increase the temperature of the air conditioning itself and not necessarily the surroundings. Also, it doesn't sound very right... to me.

"**Can you make it hotter/warmer?** Again, 'sounds a little strange. But most importantly, my roommate might be confused if he isn't thinking about the air conditioning at the time.

I still can't think of a perfectly smooth and *chill* way of expressing this sentence. Please help me out!

Comment: You want the room to be warmer, and less cold. Correct?

Comment: "Dude, can you turn down the air con?"

Comment: Can you turn down the AC? Temperatures are said to be turned down or up, aren't they? Funnily enough, turn down the AC means make it warmer.

Comment: Dude, it's freezing in here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "turning down the air conditioning" make it warmer or colder?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/does-turning-down-the-air-conditioning-make-it-warmer-or-colder) See also [Succinct and understandable term when “turn up”/“turn down” is ambiguous](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333419/succinct-and-understandable-term-when-turn-up-turn-down-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Just say "Brrr".

Comment: Suggested duplicates are poor. One asks what "turning up/down" means, and doesn't answer the main thrust of this question "What is an alternative phrase?". The other is worded sufficiently to be a dupe of this, but... it was closed as a dupe of the first one and hence hasn't actually been answered.

Answer (score 1):

In my UK based experience, "air-con" makes things cold. (Side note:It also makes the air dryer; useful when de-condensing your car's windscreen.) You could therefore say "turn the heating up" or maybe even just "turn the heat up".

The US typically has HVAC (Heating, Ventilation And Cooling) systems. Therefore, potentially saying "turn the HVAC up" might work.

The target heat is controlled by something called a thermostat. Therefore you could consider "turn the thermostat up".

Comment: I live in a subtropical area where we rarely use heaters (we use them only during SOME winters). Pretty much every room here in Hong Kong only has an air conditioner and nothing else (not literally).  Our room uses one of these: http://www.mitsubishi-ryoden.com.hk/products/catalog_list.php?cat=1&type=11 (no advertisement intended; I don't even mind which air con brand I have). So, thermostat and HVAC sound foreign to me (By the way, if it stands for Heating, Ventilation and Cooling, isn't it supposed to be HVC? What exactly were the Americans thinking?); perhaps we just talk about the air con?